# Using Clojure's filter to find entry with minimum value

Tags: clojure

I developed a function using Clojure that returns the row with the minimum value determined. Here is the function that does that:

```
(#(reduce (fn [r1 r2] (let [v1 (read-string (apply str (clojure.string/split (get r1 %2) (re-pattern " ")))) 
                            v2 (read-string (apply str (clojure.string/split (get r2 %2) (re-pattern " "))))]
                     (if (< v1 v2) r1 r2))) %1) [[1 "2007 05 18"] [2 "2004 06 15"] [3 "2004 06 10"]] 1)
```

Returns:

```
[3 "2004 06 10"]
```

Question is I want to implement the above function as  predicate for a filter function that will return the same result as the above function. Please how do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the reasonable assumption that what you have are dates, and you want the row with the lower date.

This is an approach using `sort-by`.

```
  (sort-by  (fn [[idx date]]
              (let [[_ y m d] (re-find #"\d{4} \d{2} \d{2}" date)]
                  y))
           [[1 "2007 05 18"] [2 "2004 06 15"] [3 "2004 06 10"]])
```

Or you can parse the input string as a date and avoid the `regex` all together with the added benefit of properly sorting by year, month and day.

```
  (sort-by  (fn [[idx date]]
              (.parse (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy MM dd") date))
            [[1 "2007 05 18"] [2 "2004 06 15"] [3 "2004 06 10"]])

    => ([3 "2004 06 10"] [2 "2004 06 15"] [1 "2007 05 18"])
```

Then just take `first` or `last` of the result for the lowest or highest valued row.

Using `filter` makes no sense, since `filter` doesn't accumulate state, which you need in order to compare rows among each other. (That's what you're doing manually with your `reduce` function).

Filtering the sequence with a predicate would give you all rows matching the predicate, but would say nothing about the relationship between rows themselves.

That's why `sort-by` is the idiomatic way to sort with a custom function in this situation.

Even better, if you assume the lexicographic sort of your stringified date matches with the order you want, you can just do:

```
  (sort-by second [[1 "2007 05 18"] [2 "2004 06 15"] [3 "2004 06 10"]])
  => ([3 "2004 06 10"] [2 "2004 06 15"] [1 "2007 05 18"])
```

Comment: Thanks @Guillermo Winkler